# How to show PDF file only in intent chooser

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent-chooser

I am working on an application in which a user selects a pdf file and then it gets uploaded on firebase. The problem is when a user wants to select a file then other files which are not pdf are also shown. I want to restrict it and want to show pdf files only.

I am using this code to select pdf files only but its showing other files as well.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF file"), FILE_CHOOSER);
```

How can i do it? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code to open PDF files only.

```
String[] supportedMimeTypes = {"application/pdf"};
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                intent.setType(supportedMimeTypes.length == 1 ? supportedMimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
                if (supportedMimeTypes.length > 0) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, supportedMimeTypes);
                }
            } else {
                String mimeTypes = "";
                for (String mimeType : supportedMimeTypes) {
                    mimeTypes += mimeType + "|";
                }
                intent.setType(mimeTypes.substring(0,mimeTypes.length() - 1));
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);
```

Comment: I think don't answer in API 24 to up. are you sure???